# Using Insertxml to Google Sheets. Any ideas on how to get rid of the "Formula Parse Error"?

Tags: xml, xpath, google-sheets

I'm trying to use insertxml on Google Sheets to grab updated pricing from a website. I can't seem to figure out why I'm getting a Formula Parse Error everytime.

Here's the code I'm trying to use.

```
=IMPORTXML( “https://www.menards.com/main/lighting-ceiling-fans/ceiling-fans/indoor-ceiling-fans/patriot-lighting-reg-gilford-52-led-ceiling-fan/20200/p-1502778723314-c-7488.htm”,"//div[@class='d-inline']//span[@class='d-none',data-at-id='itemFinalPrice']")
```

I've tried getting rid of the `class='d-none'` as well with no effect.

Any ideas on getting this up and running?

Comment: What did you want to imply by using the **,data-at-id='itemFinalPrice']** construct? It doesn't look like a legit XPath expression.

Answer (score 1):

How about this modification of xpath? In your case, `data-at-id` is used as the attribute like `@data-at-id`. And `,` is modified to `and`.

#### From:

```
//div[@class='d-inline']//span[@class='d-none',data-at-id='itemFinalPrice']
```

#### To:

```
//div[@class='d-inline']//span[@class='d-none' and @data-at-id='itemFinalPrice']
```

or

```
//span[@class='d-none' and @data-at-id='itemFinalPrice']
```

or

```
//span[@data-at-id='itemFinalPrice']
```

#### Result:

[image]

- In this case, the URL is put to the cell "A1". And the formula of `=IMPORTXML(A1,"//div[@class='d-inline']//span[@class='d-none' and @data-at-id='itemFinalPrice']")` is used.

If I misunderstood your question and this was not the direction you want, I apologize.